# Button pinned to bottom of layout moves with softKeyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a login screen with an ImageView"pinned" (using layout constraints) to the bottom of my Parent ConstraintLayout. I have tried just about everything I can find on SE to get my image to stay put when the soft keyboard pops up, but to no avail. I have to wonder if that's because I pinned the image to the bottom of the view?

XML for the ImageView

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="152dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/half_frog" />
```

Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginScreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
         />
```

Comment: you want the image to pin down even though the keyboard is shown?

Comment: Yes. The image is clickable and says "create account". So I don't want it to move when the user is typing in their login info. also, when it moves up, it covers up several buttons and an EditText

Comment: Just use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize". Using this only edittext adjusts.

Comment: didnt work for me

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of it ?